# Can not preview multiple uploading files in form

Tags: javascript, forms, multifile-uploader

In a multipart form, I can preview a single uploading image using:

```
 function readURL(input) {
      if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
          let image = new Image();
          image.src = `${e.target.result}`;
          image.className = "img-thumbnail"
          let closeBtn = `<button type="button" class="close"></button>`;
          let wrapper = $('<div class="image-wrapper" />');
          $('#images-to-upload').append(wrapper);
          $(wrapper).append(image);
          $(wrapper).append(closeBtn);
        }
    
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]); 
      }
    }
    
    $("#imgInput").change(function () {
      readURL(this);
    });
```

But I'd like to preview ALL uploading images, so I made this adjustment to the code above by adding a for loop:

```
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    let files = input.files;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (e) {
        let image = new Image();
        image.src = `${e.target.result[i]}`;
        image.className = "img-thumbnail"
        let closeBtn = `<button type="button" class="close"></button>`;
        let wrapper = $('<div class="image-wrapper" />');
        $('#images-to-upload').append(wrapper);
        $(wrapper).append(image);
        $(wrapper).append(closeBtn);
  
      }
      };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]); // error here
  }
}
```

But now I get this error:

```
143 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);` is outside the loop. But this is not how you do this. The `FileReader` can process only one file at the time. This means you have to create an instance of the `FileReader` for each image in the input.

I would suggest to split it into 2 functions for readability.

```
function previewImage(file) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (e) {
    let image = new Image();
    image.src = e.target.result;
    image.className = "img-thumbnail";
    let closeBtn = `<button type="button" class="close"></button>`;
    let wrapper = $('<div class="image-wrapper" />');
    $("#images-to-upload").append(wrapper);
    $(wrapper).append(image);
    $(wrapper).append(closeBtn);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files.length) {
    Array.from(input.files).forEach((file) => previewImage(file));
  }
}
```

I made some changes:

- `if (input.files.length) {` - the file input always have files `FileList` object so no need to check if it exists, and you just check if it has a length, meaning at least one file is present
- `Array.from(input.files)` - transforms `FileList` into a regular array fo you can use array functions, like `forEach`

The rest is pretty much the same. In `image.src = e.target.result;`, there's no need to make it string as it is already a string. Also the result set on the `FileReader` class cannot be array.

Comment: Works great. Thanks for the solution and explanations!